# Action at a paragraph field doesn't work with type command in IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Want to find the CSS locator to add the input in the paragraph.

```
<div class="fr-element fr-view" style="min-height: 400px;" dir="auto" spellcheck="true" contenteditable="true">
<p style="">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do here. Anything in a paragraph tag is a piece of static content on the page, It's not an input field you can type into. 

Can you explain what you're trying to achieve in a bit more detail and give examples of what you've tried so far

Comment: You can't use type since it's not an input box. If you want run javascript to add in text you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

The css would be

```
css=.fr-view.fr-element p
```

You can manipulate this using javascript within the IDE:

```
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>document.querySelectorAll('.fr-view.fr-element p')[0].innerHTML='Some New Text'</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```